# Applying same toggle for two separate elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have two block elements stacked on top of each other. When a user clicks on the top, it's supposed to toggle the content within that block, while the block  below the first stays inactive showing no content. The code I have here opens both of them regardless of which one is clicked. I have my current code add and take away a class of 'active' to mark the div to display: block or none.

What am I missing?

```js
function DropDown(element) {
  this.title = element;
  this.initEvents();
}

DropDown.prototype = {
  initEvents: function() {
    var obj = this;
    obj.title.on('click', function(event) {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  }
}

$(function() {
  var title = new DropDown($('.title'));
  $(document).click(function() {
    $('.drop').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- block 1 -->
<div class="block1">
  <h3>
    <a href="#" class="title">Title 1<span class="pull-right plus">+</span></a>

  </h3>
  <div class="drop">
    <p class="clearfix">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vitae sagittis est. Quisque dictum nibh justo, non venenatis lorem hendrerit lobortis. Nam eget volutpat tortor, nec blandit urna. In et purus et ipsum vestibulum sagittis nec et lacus. Sed
      gravida justo sed urna faucibus fermentum. Phasellus mollis, arcu et semper placerat, nibh leo fringilla ex, ac dictum turpis nisl sed justo. Etiam non eros tristique, ultrices odio vel, faucibus felis. Cras lorem diam, aliquet ac diam quis, suscipit
      dictum risus. Aliquam fringilla volutpat nulla at cursus. Cras suscipit lacus massa, scelerisque laoreet mi faucibus a.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- block 2 -->
<div class="block2">
  <h3>
    <a href="#" class="title">Title 2<span class="pull-right plus">+</span></a>

  </h3>
  <div class="drop">
    <p class="clearfix">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vitae sagittis est. Quisque dictum nibh justo, non venenatis lorem hendrerit lobortis. Nam eget volutpat tortor, nec blandit urna. In et purus et ipsum vestibulum sagittis nec et lacus. Sed
      gravida justo sed urna faucibus fermentum. Phasellus mollis, arcu et semper placerat, nibh leo fringilla ex, ac dictum turpis nisl sed justo. Etiam non eros tristique, ultrices odio vel, faucibus felis. Cras lorem diam, aliquet ac diam quis, suscipit
      dictum risus. Aliquam fringilla volutpat nulla at cursus. Cras suscipit lacus massa, scelerisque laoreet mi faucibus a.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are referencing the elements by class, so when you click all the elements with this class are affected. You can also use jquery for this.

Comment: Quotes missing from `$(.drop)`?

Comment: A fiddle replicating your problem would be helpful here.

Comment: Your dropdown code seems to work fine, but your `$(document).click` is off.

Comment: You have curly quotes in your HTML, that's not valid. You have to use ASCII single or double quotes around HTML attributes.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah I had this in a textedit doc right before I pasted it in, but rest assured in my normal doc it's not like that.

Comment: Just went through your code... you are adding a class of  "active" on the "title" and then removing it from ".drop" ?? is this the full code above?

Comment: @Barmar ... our comments crossed :)

Comment: @KingSize yes it is. I'm making edits to it by adding a jsFiddle example to help. Adding the active class makes the style of the element display: block. So initially, without it in the HTML its current state is to be display: none.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan care to elaborate? What do you mean by off?

Comment: I understand the purpose of the class "active". However, I am a bit confused about where exactly you want it. You want this class on the element with "title" class or do you want it with the element with "drop" class.

Comment: @EugeneRoss your original code had no quotes around `.drop`, but they appear there now. I'm not sure I understand the purpose though. You add a class `active` to `.title` element via the title click, then immediately remove all `active` classes from all `.drop` elements via the document click.

Comment: @KingSize I would want it on the "drop" class. But I just realized that I made a dumb error in not running my gulp task to compile my JS to view changes. Now I'm seeing why everyone can't get my code to work :')

Comment: @JesseKernaghan my goal was to add the "active" class onto the "drop" class once it had been clicked without opening the other block element that has the same exact structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle for you. This is updated and is working. Check this out if this is what you are looking for. I can then explain you what is done [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o63jk6au/).

```
obj.title.on('click', function(event) {
        $(this).parent().next('.drop').toggleClass('active');
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

The change is did here is with where the active class is being toggled. I am toggling it on the "drop" element instead of "title" element.

Comment: Yup! This was what I wanted to achieve. I must've not made it very clear where I wanted the class to be added to.

Comment: After sometime of using this, I see that when you have on of the drop down elements open, clicking anywhere on the document closes that open element. I'm not sure why that is happening per your code within the fiddle.

Comment: That is because of this function "$(document).click(function() {
   $(".drop").removeClass('active');
  });". If you do not wish this functionality, you may remove it.